# Software for Exploded Views

Tags: car, repair, parts, software, diagram

I would like to know if there is any software that allows me to see the exploded view of the various parts/components of the car.

I´m looking for something like ETKA for VAG cars but I would like to know if there is a more general solution that has most of the European car brands.

I have used HaynesPro and TecDoc but they have very few diagrams per model and they are all focused on the same thing (Gearbox fill and draing plug location, some diagrams to show torque specs, Air conditioning Service locations...) they are good but I would like to know if there is a more complete solution.

Comment: I know this seems pretty stupid, but have you tried searching with Google image search for possible lead(s) based on any images that you like? In other words, find parts diagrams and find their source. Also, manufacturer part website tend to have some degree of exploded diagrams, though I suspect they aren't at the level you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Exploded views are composed of individual drawings of the parts, assemblies constructed from cad/cam may be able to do this via software.

Answer (score 0):

My Mechanic uses [ELEKAT](https://www.carat-gruppe.de/webelekat20) to order parts, but it also ha a lot of documentation and Exploded views on a lot of those Parts.

As I understand this is a German market solution and you didn´t state where you come from, but I believe there are similar solutions on other countries.

So it is generally a good idea to search for parts-vendors that provide a Band-independent service as most of them have some documentation for identification and installation of the parts you could order.